# Using the Range and Union methods from Win32com Python

Tags: python, excel, range, win32com

a new Python Programmer here. I have a problem and hopefully you could help me. What I am doing is that I am tagging cells in an Excel Sheet through Python. And suppose I define a name for a huge no of cells at a time I am required to use Union. So it will be a Union of ranges. Now I was looking at the VBA code and translating them to Python syntax using win32com. If the Range is a few cells say 50 or so, I dont need Union but for large no of cells I would. Here's where the problem lies. I have come up with the following code, but i end up getting the

"TypeError: The Python instance can not be converted to a COM object "
error.

```
from traits.api import HasTraits, Str, Int, Button,CStr, List
from win32com.client import gencache
import win32com.client,sys,os

class cellTagging(HasTraits):

    wb = "" 
    Data = CStr
    parameter = Str
    read_Write = Str
    sheet = Str
    cell_No = List
    cell_Value = Str
    excel = win32com.client.gencache.EnsureDispatch('Excel.Application')


    def _cell_No_changed(self):
        path=os.getcwd()
        fName = os.path.join(path, sys.argv[1])
        self.wb = cellTagging.excel.Workbooks.Open(fName)
        she = self.wb.ActiveSheet
        length = len(self.cell_No)
        r = []
        for i in self.cell_No:
            r.append(she.Range(",".join(i)))
        print r
        print(r[0])
        print r[1]
        print r[2]
        h = "%s " * len(r) % tuple(r)
        string = h[:-1]
        cellTagging.excel.Union(h).Name = "Test1"
        self.wb.Close(SaveChanges = 1)

    def Run_Macro(self,Macro):
        path=os.getcwd()
        fName = os.path.join(path, sys.argv[1])
        self.wb = cellTagging.excel.Workbooks.Open(fName)
        cellTagging.excel.Application.Run(Macro)
        self.wb.Close(SaveChanges = 1)

if __name__=='__main__':
    cellTagging( parameter = 'demo', read_Write = 'Read', sheet  = 'Testing1', cell_No =        [['A86', 'A87', 'A88', 'A89', 'A90', 'A91', 'A92', 'A93', 'A94', 'A95', 'A96', 'A97', 'A98', 'A99', 'A100', 'A101', 'A102', 'A103', 'A104', 'A105', 'A4', 'B4', 'C4', 'D4', 'E4', 'F4', 'G4', 'H4', 'I4', 'J4', 'K4', 'L4', 'M4', 'N4', 'O4', 'P4', 'Q4', 'R4', 'S4', 'T4', 'U4', 'V4', 'W4', 'X4', 'Y4', 'Z4', 'AA4', 'AB4', 'AC4', 'AD4'], ['AE4', 'AF4', 'AG4', 'AH4', 'AI4', 'AJ4', 'AK4', 'AL4', 'AM4', 'AN4', 'AO4', 'AP4', 'AQ4', 'AR4', 'AS4', 'AT4', 'AU4', 'AV4', 'AW4', 'AX4', 'AY4', 'AZ4', 'BA4', 'BB4', 'BC4', 'BD4', 'BE4', 'BF4', 'BG4', 'BH4', 'BI4', 'BJ4', 'BK4', 'BL4', 'BM4', 'BN4', 'BO4', 'BP4', 'BQ4', 'BR4', 'BS4', 'BT4', 'BU4', 'BV4', 'BW4', 'BX4', 'BY4', 'BZ4', 'CA4', 'CB4'], ['CC4', 'CD4', 'CE4', 'CF4', 'CG4', 'CH4', 'CI4', 'CJ4', 'CK4', 'CL4', 'CM4', 'CN4', 'CO4', 'CP4', 'CQ4', 'CR4', 'CS4', 'CT4', 'CU4', 'CV4', 'CW4', 'CX4', 'CY4', 'CZ4', 'DA4', 'DB4']])
```

The line 
       hello = cellTagging.excel.Union(h).Name = "Test1"
gives me the "TypeError: The Python instance can not be converted to a COM object" error

PS: But when I put the list elements(Ranges) directly as
      hello = cellTagging.excel.Union(r[0],r[1],r[2]).Name = "Test1"

it works. I am confused any insights would be appreciated!Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [Union Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa213609%28v=office.11%29.aspx), the union method looks like:

```
 expression.Union(Arg1, Arg2, ...)
```

But your code will pass a single string.

```
h = "%s " * len(r) % tuple(r)    
...
hello = cellTagging.excel.Union(h).Name = "Test1"
```

Whereas:

```
hello = cellTagging.excel.Union(r[0],r[1],r[2]).Name = "Test1"
```

Will pass in a three parameters.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. Pardon my naiveity. So I tried converting my List r to a Tuple tup i.e. tup = tuple(r). But when I give the "tup" argument to Union it still gives me the same error. Would you be kind enough to show me how could I go about changing the code the right way! Thanks

Comment: Sry, corrected my answer. You can unpack a tuple for function calls with a preceding *. E.g. tup1 = (1,2,3) use *tup1 or tup1[0],tup1[1],tup1[2] (like you already did in your "working" example).

Comment: I tried unpacking too. Still get the same error. this is what I did. SO far I have the r list with all the ranges in it. tup = tuple(r); cellTagging.excel.Union(*tup).Name = "Test1". Still end up with the same erorr. Thanks

Comment: And if you're using the same list r with r[0],r[1],r[2] in the function call it is working? Btw if r is already a list you can directly use it in the function call with a preceding *

Comment: Yes I tried that with List as well :-P. Yes thats right individually they work but when I Unpack the error.

Comment: Wow. I just figured it out!!! Thank you for your help. heres what I did . I changed the list r to a class level list rather than function level. And used self.r everywhere in the function and it worked. I wounder whats different from earlier! Anyways, if it wasnt for you keeping me engaged I wouldnt have tried :) Thanks again.

Comment: Great :-) Just finished to rebuild that sample code. Created two ranges with myRange1 = openedWorkbook.Worksheets("Test1").Range("A1:B2") and myRange2 = openedWorkbook.Worksheets("Test1").Range( "A2:B3" ). Afterwards stuffed them also in a list ranges_list = [myRange1, myRange2]. Then both ways worked: self.exceldispatch.Union( myRange1, myRange2 ).Name = "Test1" and also self.exceldispatch.Union( *ranges_list ).Name = "Test1"

Comment: I guess this also only works for small lists but doesnt work for big ones either. I just tried a list with 267 items and got an error `TypeError: Union() takes from 1 to 31 positional arguments but 268 were given`